# Passing radio input from view to controller codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I want the selected value to pass from view to controller but it's not working, I've tried a hundred diffrent ways to make it happen, I've tried using checkbox instead of radio and it worked, but I couldn't select the product, it just kept selecting the first product, using set radio, I saw that when I want to select the product, it adds checked=checked but it doesn't pass to controller.

Controller.php

```
public function form()


    {


            helper(['form']);

    
            $projectModel = new ProjectsModel();


            if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {


                    $rules = [


                            'firstname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                            'lastname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                            'email' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[60]|valid_email|is_unique[accounts.email]',
                            'company' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                            'location' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                            'address' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
                            'product' => 'required',
                            


                    ];


                    if(!$this->validate($rules)) {
                            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
                    }

                    else {

                            $newData = [
                                    'id' => session()->get('os_id'),
                                    'firstname' => $this->request->getVar('firstname'),
                                    'lastname' => $this->request->getVar('lastname'),
                                    'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                                    'company' => $this->request->getVar('company'),
                                    'location' => $this->request->getVar('location'),
                                    'address' => $this->request->getVar('address'),
                                    'product' => $this->request->getVar('product'),

                            ];

                            $projectModel->save($newData);

                            session()->setFlashdata('success', 'Successful updated');
                            return redirect()->to('form/success');
                    }

            }


            $data['user'] = $projectModel->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();
            
            echo view('templates/header', $data);
            echo view('form', $data);
            echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

View.php

/>

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shirt">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('product', '2'); ?> />
          <div class="icon">
              <img class="icons" src="../shirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="Chiloti">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="3" <?php echo set_radio('product', '3'); ?> />
         <div class="icon">
             <img class="icons" src="../tshirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shirt">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="4" <?php echo set_radio('product', '4'); ?> />
          <div class="icon">
              <img class="icons" src="../shirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shirt">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="5" <?php echo set_radio('product', '5'); ?> />
          <div class="icon">
              <img class="icons" src="../shirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shirt">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="5" <?php echo set_radio('product', '6'); ?> />
          <div class="icon">
              <img class="icons" src="../shirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="Chiloti">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="7" <?php echo set_radio('product', '7'); ?> />
         <div class="icon">
             <img class="icons" src="../tshirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shirt">
       <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="8" <?php echo set_radio('product', '8'); ?> />
          <div class="icon">
              <img class="icons" src="../shirt.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="shoes">
        <input type="radio" name="product[]" value="9" <?php echo set_radio('product', '9'); ?> />
                      <div class="icon">
                       <img class="icons" src="shoes.svg" alt="" style="width:45%;margin-top: 25%;">
                     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab, but according to [CI's documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_radio#set_radio), the first argument to `set_radio` is supposed to be the name attribute of the field.

You've given this radio group a common name of "product[]" but you're passing "product" as the first argument to `set_radio`.

I'm looking at the code for `set_radio` and it doesn't do any magic with square brackets so I don't see any reason those two strings would match up.

Comment: Yea, the brackets are there because I tried to make it for multiple images, after a few hours I finally find out why it wasn't working. It was caused by something in JS.